# How can i create a trigger that will only update a record if the new record is different from the old record?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers

Question is create a trigger that will only update a record if the old record is different from the new. Can i get some help please i don't even know how to start the syntax apart from

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_marketingliste
ON marketing_list FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM INSERTED
END
```

Comment: Why do you need a trigger to only update if the value is new?  If the value is not new then it just replaces the value with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the schema is but the sample code below should help you to understand how this can be done.

SET NOCOUNT ON 
GO

CREATE TABLE test(col1 int primary key , col2 int )
go

CREATE TRIGGER trg_test_upd on test 
INSTEAD OF UPDATE 
AS 
BEGIN

```
            IF  EXISTS (
                                SELECT * 
                                FROM Deleted  del -- old value
                                INNER JOIN Inserted ins  -- new value
                                on del.col1 = ins.col1 
                                and del.col2 = ins.col2)
            BEGIN 

                PRINT 'No Update'
                RETURN  --if old value is same as new value dont update
            END 
            ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                            UPDATE t1
                            set col2  = i.col2
                            from dbo.test t1 
                            inner join inserted i 
                            on t1.col1 = i.col1 

            END
```

END 
go

Insert into test (col1, col2)
select 10, 10
go

update test 
set col2 = 200
where col1 = 10

SELECT *
FROM TEST

--This would not do the update 
update test 
set col2 = 200

GO

Drop table test 
go